# What is the control qubit in this 1D ladder of controlled Z gates?

Tags: quantum-gate

[image]

In the picture above, the last layer with dot-shape, is called 1D ladder of controlled Z gates. It is stated in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-07090-4) to show the barren plateau issue. I want to know which is the control qubit, the higher one or the lower one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Controlled Z gate is symmetric with respect to the two qubits.

Its action in the computational basis is to leave the states $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$ unchanged and to flip the phase of the state $|11\rangle$. Consequently, it does not matter which qubit we designate as control: it flips the phase only if both qubits are in state $|1\rangle$.

You can also see this from its matrix

$$
CZ = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Swapping qubits corresponds to swapping the two middle columns and the two middle rows and in the case of CZ this transformation does not change the matrix.

Comment: I notice it's a stupid question, sorry. But I just can't think it out a few minutes ago...

Comment: Admittedly the name "controlled-Z" does suggest that one of the qubits serves a different role than the other! I suppose the symmetric symbol is trying to rectify the confusing name...